# CollectionView does not scroll when added to view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Here is my code:

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = .greatestFiniteMagnitude
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 15
layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: screenWidth*0.2, height: screenHeight*0.15)
       
collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth*0.9, height: screenHeight*0.15), collectionViewLayout: layout)
collectionView?.layer.zPosition = 10
collectionView?.register(PlantSnapshotCell.self,forCellWithReuseIdentifier:PlantSnapshotCell.identifier)
collectionView?.backgroundColor = .clear
collectionView?.alwaysBounceHorizontal = true
collectionView?.bounces = true
collectionView?.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
       
collectionView?.dataSource = self
collectionView?.delegate = self
       
scrollView.addSubview(collectionView!)
view.addSubview(scrollView)
```

It renders in the view, but any sort of interaction does not work. The width of the collectionView is 90% the width of the superview. Scrolling horizontally does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are adding `collectionView` as a subview to the `scrollView`?

Comment: `scrollView` is just a poorly named `UIView` rather than a `UIScrollView`. The reason behind the "nested" `addSubviews` is because I want the `collectionView` to be overlaid on an isometric view in the background